# how to access google coral using different network

Tags: vnc-server, google-coral

I'm able to access google coral via putty using same network. But is it possible to access google coral using different network (like VNC server)

Regards
Rahul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved the problem. Checked with google support officially you can't connect google coral with different network. But incase if you want to connect within same network this is how you will connect.

1. generate key using puttygen.
2. once key is generated store public/private key (.ppk).
3. copy public key and paste in authorized_key location.
4. once public key is pasted get the broadcast ip address by hitting below command
   mdt shell 
   ip addr | grep wlan0
5. Load ppk file in putty/winscp and pass the ip address which we got after running above command.
6. Google coral is now successfully connected with putty/winscp

Answer (score 2):

If you would like to access the google coral through remote ssh e.g. putty or another ssh service you can change the ssh permissions:

```
sudo nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

and set:

```
ChallengeResponseAuthentication yes
PasswordAuthentication yes
```

save the file and restart the ssh service:

```
sudo systemctl restart ssh
```

Remote ssh should work now. To get the vnc server working the coral would need a GUI which it does not have.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Is there anyway to connect ssh from internet ? I am using Huawei 4g dongle and unable to figure port forwarding. Any other way you know?